# ERC721 is being minted to null address

Tags: truffle, erc-721, truffle-contract

Here is the contract code to mint ERC721 tokens:

```
contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {

    mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    constructor()ERC721 ("Lambo", "LMB") public {}

    function mintNFT(address to, uint256 tokenId, string memory tokenURI) public {
        require(to != address(0), "ERC721: token mint to contract owner address");
        require(!_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: token already minted");
        _mint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI);
    }

    function burnToken(uint256 tokenId) public {
        _burn(tokenId);
    }

    function balanceOf(address owner) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: balance query for zero address");
        return _balances[owner];
    }

    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
        address owner = _owners[tokenId];
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Writing tests to mint ERC721 tokens and verify if the minted addresses owns the token:

```
const firstMinter = accounts[4]; //0xD235287FcBE172407F5692Bc25cD73989a7d6777

it("Minting ERC721 Tokens", async() => {
        let nftInstance = await mintNFTs.deployed();

        await nftInstance.mintNFT(firstMinter, 1, "ipfs://QmQZTUekV9P7cKRiVVwdahyaFNZEt6Yt7fGtcRfsLSWpyP/evocube.json");

        console.log("ERC721 Tokens have been minted for whitelist")
    })

    it("Verifying Whitelist Owners have ERC721 Tokens", async() => {

        const nftInstance = await mintNFTs.deployed();

        let firstOwner = await nftInstance.ownerOf(1);
        console.log(firstOwner);
        assert.equal(firstMinter, firstOwner, "Error: First Minter doesn't own the token");
    })
```

Here are the test results I am receiving:

> AssertionError: Error: First Minter doesn't own the token: expected
> '0xD235287FcBE172407F5692Bc25cD73989a7d6777' to equal
> '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

Comment: I think your deployed contract might be a fresh instance each time you call the deployed.
Try to validate by calling total supply.

Comment: I merged NFT owner verification code within the mint code yet it's giving the same error.

Comment: So you might want to test further to figure out why? BalanceOf, total Supply, did the Mint happen correctly?

Comment: Which ERC721 contract are you using?

Comment: Which ERC721 as in the token ID? It's minted with id 1 and queried for Id 1

Comment: @MadeInDreams I am using ERC721URIStorage and Ownable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here, the firstMinter is still haven't own the NFT yet before deployed tokenID 1, so the firstOwner is null.

```
assert.equal(firstMinter, firstOwner, "Error: First Minter doesn't own the token");
```